# Jquery datatable search not functioning

Tags: jquery, grails, datatable

My table is as follows

```
$list.dataTable({
    "bPaginate": false,
    "bInfo": false,
    "aoColumns": [
      null, // name
      {"bVisible": false, "bSearchable": true, "bSortable": true}, // languages
    ]
  });
```

In the table I have

```
Name      Languages
Marco     java,javascript,php
```

Now when I search for php or marco it filters fine but when I search for java or javascript it does not display anything.

I don't understand what could be the problem.

DataTables version: 1.9.4
Grails version: 2.2.1

Comment: do you see any errors in the console ?

Comment: Nope, no errors. Every other word that I've tried filters fine except java and javascript...